# Rails where / find_all with multiple id same column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, model

Hello I'm looking for a clean way (overide .where method??) to retrieve from DB multiple rows with multiples ids of the same column,

Example:

```
# Actual ugly mode
args = {}
args[:channel] = common_channel

args[:writer] = userA
args[:receiver] = userB
journalsA = Journal.where args

args[:writer] = userB
args[:receiver] = userA
journalsB = Journal.where args
# @journals = journalsA + journalsB
```

How can I make something like this: `Journals.where userA: userA, userB: userB, channel:x` where `user(A|B)` points to `writer` and `receiver` at the same time

Do I need to use a custom SQL line or exist some fancy rails way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can think of what you are asking as: Can you write a OR query in Rails? The answer is yes, but with SQL fragments:

```
Journal.where(channel: common_channel).where('(writer = ? AND receiver = ?) OR (writer = ? AND receiver = ?)', userA, userB, userB, userA)
```